# EOFException at GsonResponseBodyConverter with errorBody()

Tags: error-handling, httpresponse, retrofit2, eofexception, android, gson

I'm following [DeserializeErrorBody.java](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/samples/src/main/java/com/example/retrofit/DeserializeErrorBody.java) as a guide

When I use `Converter<ResponseBody, Error> errorConverter`, Error being a POJO class for my errors, I would get an EOFException trying to do `errorConverter.convert(response.errorBody());` with the log being:`java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 1 path$...`

If I were to log `erroBody.string()` it would print the error that the server sends `{"message":"Incorrect user or password"}`

Moreover the error code at `response.code()` is `401` and the `response.body()` is `null`

Why do I get this error if the body is not null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using `Observable<ResponseBody>` for the Retrofit interface, like I would use `Call<ResponseBody`> to check only `response.isSuccessful().`
Turns out I need to use `Observable<Response<Void>>` to skip the deserialization of an empty body which causes the EOFException.